# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list when write javascript in PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've problem writing javascript in PHP code.
Here my script :

```
echo ' <script>';
echo ' $(function(){';
echo ' x = parseInt($("#counter2").val());';
echo ' $("#add_row2").click(function(){';
echo ' $("#addr2"+x).html("<td align="right">\'+ (x+1) +\'</td><td class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" name="vprice[]" class="required form-control text-right"></td><td class="col-xs-2"><input type=text" name="vminorder[]" class="required form-control text-right"></td>");';
echo ' $("#tab_logic2").append("<tr id="addr2\'+ x+1 +\'"></tr>");';
echo ' x++;';
echo ' });';
echo ' $("#delete_row2").click(function(){';
echo ' if(x> 1){';
echo ' $("#addr2"+(x-1)).html("");';
echo ' x--;';
echo ' }';
echo ' });';
echo ' });';
echo ' </script>';
```

When running it is produce an error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in line

```
echo ' $("#addr2"+x).html("<td align="right">\'+ (x+1) +\'</td><td class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" name="vprice[]" class="required form-control text-right"></td><td class="col-xs-2"><input type=text" name="vminorder[]" class="required form-control text-right"></td>");';
echo ' $("#tab_logic2").append("<tr id="addr2\'+ x+1 +\'"></tr>");';
```

Because in this line have variable I use quotes and wrap it with \ tag.
It still error.

Any sugesstion?

Comment: you dont need one echo per line

Comment: you can use [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) php syntax for doing that

Comment: and btw you should not definitely print js code using php

Comment: **When running** Where is your html file?

Comment: I'm using codeigniter framework when using heredoc it showing more error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obviously due to the crazy mixture of syntax and the confusion it causes.

First, use [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) like @Diego suggested in the comment:

```
// A single `echo`!
echo <<<EOD
<script>
    \$(function(){
        x = parseInt(\$("#counter2").val());
        \$("#add_row2").click(function(){
            \$("#addr2"+x).html("<td align='right'>" + (x+1) + "</td>" + 
                                "<td class='col-xs-2'><input type='text' name='vprice[]' class='required form-control text-right'></td>" +
                                "<td class='col-xs-2'><input type='text' name='vminorder[]' class='required form-control text-right'></td>");
            \$("#tab_logic2").append("<tr id='addr2" + (x+1) + "'></tr>");
            x++;
        });
        \$("#delete_row2").click(function(){
        if(x> 1){
            \$("#addr2"+(x-1)).html("");
            x--;
        }
    });
});
</script>
EOD;
```

In doing so, it gets rid of the outer set of quotes, which makes it somewhat easier. After that, I got rid of the double-quotes from within the HTML, which were causing problems with your jQuery `html` method.

Just the organization of code will help you prevent this in the future.

Comment: Fwiw, you cannot have line feeds as is in JS strings.

Comment: thanks @wes-foster but i'm using codeigniter framework, and it showing more error :(

Answer (score 0):

You have unbalanced quotes in your output, e.g.:

```
"<td align="right">'

"<tr id="addr2'
```

Consider using a templating engine.

And it is a good idea to separate server-side code from what it generates: if you have a client-side-related issue, first investigate the resulting code instead of server-side code.